# Using a function in another function both within the same class in PHP

Tags: php, function, class, call

I have a class with 2 functions inside it. I want to use one of the function inside the other function. Both public functions. Is this possible? I cannot get it to work.

Here is my class:

```
class scores {
    public function rightScoreTicks($idMatch, $currentScores)
    {
        include('commonItems/connectionMundial.php');   
        $rightScores = "SELECT * FROM partidos WHERE ganador <> 0 AND id = ".$idMatch;
        $resultRight = $con->prepare($rightScores);
        $resultRight->execute();
        $rightScore = $resultRight->fetchAll();

        if ($rightScore[0]['ganador'] != 0)
        {
            //echo " | (Resultado final: ".$rightScore[0]['score1']." - ".$rightScore[0]['score2'].")";
            if ($rightScore[0]['ganador'] == $currentScores[0]['ganador'])
            $rightProno = "<font style='color: green;'><strong>&#10004;</strong></font>";
            else $rightProno = "<font style='color: red;'><strong>&#x2718;</strong></font>";
            if ($rightScore[0]['score1'] == $currentScores[0]['team1'] && $rightScore[0]['score2'] == $currentScores[0]['team2'] )
            $exactScore = "<font style='color: green;'><strong>&#10004;</strong></font>";
            else $exactScore = "<font style='color: red;'><strong>&#x2718;</strong></font>";
            echo "  ".$rightProno." ".$exactScore;
        }
    }

    public function allPlayersProno ($idMatch, $idPlayer2, $bettingActive)
    {

        include('commonItems/connectionMundial.php');   
        $allpron = "SELECT * FROM predictions WHERE id_partido = ".$idMatch;
        $allPronos = $con->prepare($allpron);
        $allPronos->execute();
        $allPronosticos = $allPronos->fetchAll();

        foreach ($allPronosticos as $eachProno)
        {       
            $playerName2 = playerDetails($eachProno['id_usuario']);
            if ($eachProno['ganador'] != 0 && $eachProno['id_usuario'] != $idPlayer2)
            {
                echo "<br><span style='font-size: 12px; color: #0F753F;'>".$playerName2.": ".$eachProno['team1']." - ".$eachProno['team2'];
                $this->rightScoreTicks($comingMatch['id'], $pronoJugad);
                echo "</span>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is in the function `allPlayersProno` where I try to do `$this->rightScoreTicks($comingMatch['id'], $pronoJugad);`

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  Are you sure that snippet of code is being called?  It looks right to me.  Please add your errors and if none are being displayed, put this at the top of your code `ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: yes it is possible, what is the error you are getting?

Comment: "Undefined variable: comingMatch" and same thing for $pronoJugad. Do I need to put those variables as arguments for the allPlayersProno function too?

Comment: Yes, php has only two scopes: local and global. So you need use global keyword or pass variable to funtion.

Comment: Where is the $comingMatch and $pronoJugad variables created?  In a different class, different file?